# Why this ideal is generated by a finite set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

We know this known proposition of algebraic geometry:

[image]

After that the author writes:

[image]

Implicitly, he is saying this set $\{F^*\mid F\in I\}$ is necessarily finite, but I can't see why.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The author is saying that a finite subset of $\{F^\ast \mid F \in I\}$ generates $I^\ast$, not that $\{F^\ast \mid F \in I\}$ itself is finite.

Comment: I haven't seen the term "form" in this context. Can you tell us what it means?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews In this context, a form is just an homogeneous polynomial.

Comment: @DanielFischer ok, but why? It's not so obvious for me.

Comment: Well, $k$ is a field, isn't it? Then $k[X_1,\, \dotsc,\,X_{n+1}]$ is Noetherian, so every ideal is finitely generated.

Comment: @DanielFischer He is not necessarily saying that some finite subset of $\{F^*\}$ generates $I$, only that $I$ is homogeneous, and therefore finitely generated by forms. Yes, you can show that we can pick our generator from $\{F^*\}$, but that doesn't necessarily follow from the proposition.

Comment: @DanielFischer yes yes of course, I had forgotten this fact, thank you very much for helping me.